# Facebook Marketing API Fetching Only Facebook/Instagram Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using Facebook Marketing API to fetch Campaign, AdSet, Ad and Insight data.

I want to fetch only Facebook Campaigns or only Instagram Campaings. There is publisher_platform breakdown but I think is is only available for Insight data.

Is there a way to fetch platform specific campaign, adset, ad and insight data or is it only for insight.

I tried following example but no data was shown.

```
curl -X GET -G \
  -d 'fields="impressions"' \
  -d 'breakdown="publisher_platform"' \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<AD_SET_ID>/insights
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any filtering option, but my solution was to fetch all campaigns and adsets, specifically listing the field `targeting` on adsets. This allows you to see which `targeting.publisher_platforms` were selected. You can check them in [AdSets Field Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign#fields), for [Placement Targeting Options see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/placement-targeting).

Using a simple programming language could split adsets in two groups: Facebook and Instagram.

Please keep in mind, that you specify `publisher_platforms` on adset-level, not on campaigns. So you must decide what happens, if adsets advertising on both platforms.